# How can you exclude an item in the query set while in a for loop?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to remove

```
results = Model.objects.filter(condition - satisfied... etc.)
```

Then I loop through the queryset and remove each object as I go through my code:

```
for a in results:

### code ###

    results.exclude(id=a.id)
```

No matter how I exclude, results object does not change.  Is there a way to "pop" them as I iterate through the query set?

Comment: You need this to be a queryset?

Comment: @Gocht. I know could pull the objects from a queryset and use .remove to take them out of the list.  I was looking to see if there is a way to do it "in place".

Comment: The queryset does not update inplace. You need to recapture the queryset result into a local variable.

Comment: @karthikr. How do you do that?  I thought putting it in Results already makes it into a local variable.

Answer (score 7):

Change the last portion of your code like this:

```
for a in results:

### code ###

    results = results.exclude(id=a.id)
```

since queryset.exclude() returns a new queryset, without changing the existing.

Answer (score 2):

But you would do database query for each loop though since you calling `.exclude()` with each loop

If you just want to remove object for each loop, you could use:

```
new_list = list(results)
for a in results:  
    ### code ###
    new_list.remove(a)
```

Comment: This is an important point if time consumption of queries is an issue.  You could then filter for only things that are left in new_list (or better yet you could create a list of `remove_pks` and use `results = results.exclude(pk__in=remove_pks)` after the for loop.